# Odata expand issue when all data null in left join

Tags: .net-core, odata, webapi

I have implemented expand with odata v4 using .net core. It is working fine but creating issue when not able to find key property in expand.
Property is nullable hence EF applying left join to it. To confirm the same I also checked query in SQL profiler and that query is also working fine in SQL Server.

If I am passing all the property as select it is working fine. Let's take one example.

Model:

```
Product{
public int prodid {get,set};
public string prodname {get,set};
public string depid {get,set};
public Department department{get,set};
}

Department{
public string depid {get,set};
public string depname{get set}
}
```

working Expand odata url:

```
http://localhost:5655/prod?$count=true$select=prodid$expand=department($select=depid,depname)
value:
{
       prodid:1
      Department:
      {
            depid:133
            depname:null
      }
}
```

Not working Expand odata url:

```
http://localhost:5655/prod?$count=true$select=prodid$expand=department
Giving 500 internal server error
```

Data in DB:

```
Product table
prodid |depid |prodname
1      |133   |test

No data available in Department table for depid 133
```

Runtime in profiler it is generating below query:

```
select p.prodid,p.depid,t.depid, t.depname
from (select p.prodid,p.prodname from product p) as [p]
left join ( select d.depid, d.depname from department d) as [t] on p.depid=t.depid
result:
  prodid |p.depid |t.depid  |t.depname
  1      |133     |null     |null
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.